Updating embedded sheets charts in Slides presentation mode
is there any solution to update google sheets charts in slides presentation mode?
I found an apps script code, but it did not work in conjunction with a trigger.
function myFunction() {
  var presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var slides = presentation.getSlides();
  for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    var slide = slides[i];
    var charts = slide.getSheetsCharts();
    for (var j = 0; j < charts.length; j++) {
      var chart = charts[j];
      chart.refresh();
    }
  }
}


Please be more specific. Include the trigger details. Also include the execution logs (as text, not as images).

Thoughts on available triggers: SIMPLE: onOpen, onInstall (Editor Add-on) and INSTALLABLE: Time-driven. onInstall is a non-starter. onOpen is a Simple script which would require authentication so it can't be run as-written. However a Custom Menu could be created and the script run manually from the menu. The down-side is that the there needs to be a manual intervention. Time-driven (an Installable trigger) is a possibility but we don't know the volatility of Sheet data so timing of the Event in relation to the timing of the Presentation might be an issue.

“update google sheets charts in slides presentation mode?” Just to be clear… when a slideshow is running, the content is shown as an image and it isn’t possible to dynamically update a slideshow per se. One must update the actual Slides presentation file prior to running the Slideshow.
